# What is the sum-capacity for a non-symmetric interference channel for information theorists?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, information-theory

This question is dedicated for people who are experts in information theory.

An interesting result for a two user interference channel in information theory, is the sum-capacity to within one bit. It however was derived for the symmteric case.

I was wondering if anyone knows what the sum-capacity bound for the two user channel is, say for example user #1 wants to communicate with its own receiver at rate $R_1$ and user two communicates with receiver 2 at a rates $R_2$.

And let us say I have the following channel

$$Y_1= h_{11}X_1 + h_{12}X_2+Z_1$$
$$Y_2= h_{22}X_1 + h_{21}X_2+Z_2$$ 
where $h_{ij}$ for $i,j\in[1,2]^2$ are channel gains from receiver $j$ to transmitter $i$ and $Z_{i}$ for $i\in[1,2]$ are additive white gaussian noise mean zero variance one.

Can anyone help me write down what the sum-capacity for this general 'non' symmetric gaussian interference channel is?

Comment: For, two user non-symmetric Gaussian interference channel capacity (not just sum-capacity) is know to withing 1 bit. This result was show by Etkin, Tse, and Wang.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For, two user non-symmetric Gaussian interference channel capacity (not just sum-capacity) is know to withing 1 bit. This result was show by Etkin, Tse, and Wang.

If you have Network Information Theory book by El Gamal look at chapter 6 they have outer bound that is tight within in 1 bit.

Answer (score 1):

See ''*Sum Capacity of the Vector Gaussian Broadcast Channel and Uplink–Downlink Duality*'' by  Viswanath and David, in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory v49, No. 8, Aug 2003.

These people found that for a MIMO broadcast with $N$ antennas and $K$ users, with additive iid CCS Gaussian noise $\eta$, with a flat-fading $N\times K$ channel (gain) matrix $H$,

(All this makes the reception $\vec{y}=H^{\dagger}\vec{x}+\vec{\eta}$)

the sum capacity is:

$$\underset{D\in \mathcal{A_1}}{\sup} \log \det ( I + HDH^{\dagger})$$

with $\mathcal{A_1}$ being the set of nonnegative $N \times N$ diagonal matrices, whose trace is less than or equal to your power constraint at the broadcaster.

The 'interference' in your case is cooked into $H$.